# Difference between crystals?

Tags: crystal

Is there any point in using a big crystal over a smaller one? Apart from the tolerance spec, how come crystal manufacturers have all these different models of crystals from really tiny ones to big ones? I don't think I know the advantage to using a big crystal.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Smaller packages tend to be more expensive for the same spec. There are also often differences in frequency ranges, tempco, accuracy etc. available in different sizes

Comment: Any chance that it is the SMD sized (small) crystals that cost more ? I've purchased about 8-10 odd different valued crystals in retail, and give the picture shown above, the smaller ones were invariably cheaper (almost 50-60%) of the larger ones. In my case, both options were THT. Also, I noticed that the crystals with 4-5 decimal precision were almost 4x-5x of the other crystals. Just an observation, might mean nothing. These were all 30-50ppm ones.

Answer (score 3):

Smaller crystals of the same rated frequency may operate differently, series/parallel or fundamental/overtone.